# How to convert "file:linenumber:offset" to "file#byteoffset"

Tags: bash, file, offset

I have a symbol location of the form `file:linenumber:offset`, for example:

```
/a/b/c/transform_throttle.go:96:6
```

So it refers to line 96, column 6. How can I convert it to the format `file#byteoffset` like below, showing only the byte offset 1501 from the beginning of this (example) file?

```
/a/b/c/transform_throttle.go:#1501
```

Comment: Most text files in Unix/Linux have variable-length lines.  So there's no way to do this in general, unless you maintain your own index somewhere of how long each line is, or (more likely) what the byte offset of the beginning of each line is.

Comment: Does this have to be `bash`, or can you use Perl/Python/Ruby/C?  The reason I ask is because you really need a language which supports `"seek/tell"` functionality.

Comment: @SteveSummit agree, I'm aware of your point. This is for some trick use purpose.

Comment: @cdarke it's fine to be non bash.

Comment: @Dan Getz, thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python 3 solution :

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Usage:", sys.argv[0], "input-file output-file", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

inputfile = sys.argv[1]
outputfile = sys.argv[2]

with open(inputfile) as inf, open(outputfile, 'w') as outf:
    while True:
        pos = inf.tell()   # Get the file position before the read
        line = inf.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print("%s:%d" % (line.split(':')[0], pos), file=outf)
```

Assuming the python script is called `gash.py`, run it like this:

```
python gash.py in.txt out.txt
```

If you need python 2 (`python -V` to find your version) then the `print` statements need to be changed.

I should add that using `readline()` is not the normal way to read a file from python - usually we iterate through the file using a `for` loop.  However we need the current file position, and that is not allowed when using iteration, so we have to do it the long way.

Comment: thanks for the python solution. It looks more maintainable than bash, if there's no any standard tools to follow and you have to role your own.

Comment: @JasonXu: python is incredibly powerful compared to shells like bash, BUT it pays to learn (and use) good programming techniques with it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @cdarke that `bash` is not the best tool for this job. That being said:

```
#!/bin/bash
(( $# != 1 )) && {
    echo "usage: $0 /a/b/c/transform_throttle.go:96:6"
    exit
}

target_file=${1%%:*}
tmp=${1#*:}
target_line=${tmp%:*}
target_offset=${tmp#*:}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    (( linenum++ ))
    if (( linenum == target_line )); then
        (( byteoffset += target_offset ))
        echo $target_file:#$byteoffset
        exit
    else
        (( byteoffset += (${#line} + 1) ))  # +1 for newline
    fi
done < $target_file
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. My fault for not mentioning it's not strongly limited to bash.

Answer (score 0):

What I have sometimes done is maintained an auxiliary index mapping input file lines to byte offsets.  Here is a stripped-down example:

```
function mkindex {
    grep --byte-offset ^ $1 | sed 's/:.*//' > $2
}

# usage: findoffset file line char

file=$1
line=$2
char=$3
ix=.$file.ix

if test ! -f $ix -o $file -nt $ix
then    mkindex $file $ix
fi

o1=`sed -n ${line}p $ix`
if test -z "$o1"; then echo "$0: $file: nonexistent line $line" >&2; exit 1; fi
o2=`expr $o1 + $char - 1`

echo $file:$o2
```

Invoked as

```
script /a/b/c/transform_throttle.go 96 6
```

this should give you the output you want.

It has one inefficiency: it performs an expensive linear search in its index file for the line it needs.  It would be better to use binary search.  (I've written binary searches in sh, although it's a bit of a mess.  A command-line binary-search utility would be nice, but I don't know of a standard one.  I use https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/#bsearch .)

It complains about nonexistent lines, but it doesn't do anything clever with nonexistent columns within lines.  It's also missing error-checking on missing files.  If you don't want it littering your directories with index files it never deletes, you won't want to use this kind of solution.

[Oh, and I suppose I should apologize for my old-school backtic and `expr` usage.  I guess all the cool bash kids are using its newer features.]